# How to update content of one column of a row by another column of another row in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which have following structure--

```
table propiedad--

codigo        codpropietario    
 14                 17
 15                 16
 16                 15
 17                 8

another table wp_posts

ID              codigo
1001               17
1002               16
1003               15   
1004               8
```

I want to update `codpropietario` column of table `propiedad` with `ID` column of table `wp_posts` if condition `propiedad.codpropietario=wp_posts.codigo`.

I want table propiedad table in this form-

```
codigo    codpropietario
14             1001
15             1002
16             1003 
17             1004
```

I hope It makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
UPDATE propiedad t1 
JOIN wp_posts t2 
ON t1.codpropietario=t2.codigo 
SET t1.codpropietario=t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to update the table.

```
update propiedad p
join wp_posts wp on wp.codigo = p.codpropietario
set p.codpropietario = wp.ID
```